# PHPQuery - getting the image width and height

Tags: php, phpquery

I am parsing a page using PHPQuery.

At some point I have obtained all images on the page using:

```
$url = "http://mywebsite.com";
$all = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($url, $charset = 'utf-8');

// list of all images
$imgsrc = $all->find('img');
```

now I am interacting this list

```
foreach ($imgsrc as $img) {

   $width  = need magic command to extract image width
   $height = need magic command to extract image height

}
```

The problem is this. The img attribute does not have a `width` or a `height` attribute but its class has.

The image tag is like this:

```
<img src="img1.png" class="alfa">
```

I need to get the width and height defined by that class.

I can get the class name by doing

```
$className = pq($img)->attr('class');
```

How do I do obtain the width/height of that class now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
```

to get the image height and width.